# Cannot add files to a repository

Tags: svn

I'm trying to add a directory (it contains a site) into a repository:

```
svn import /path file:///var/svn/repos/project -m "Initial state"
```

But instead of getting:

```
Adding xxx.php
Adding xx2.php
....
```

I get lots of strange lines. E.g.:

```
[ 0 string,=\211PNG,"image/png"]
4294967190 == 0 = 0
mget @0: \037\213\b\000\370\325\344L\000\003\354<\373s\332\306\326\375\325\376+62\267@B0\344&\355\255\035

[ 0 string,=\212MNG,"video/x-mng"]
4294967189 == 0 = 0
mget @0: \037\213\b\000\370\325\344L\000\003\354<\373s\332\306\326\375\325\376+62\267@B0\344&\355\255\035

[ 0 belong,=235082497,"Hierarchical Data Format (version 4) data"]
529205248 == 235082497 = 0
mget @0: \037\213\b\000\370\325\344L\000\003\354<\373s\332\306\326\375\325\376+62\267@B0\344&\355\255\035

[ 0 string,=\211HDF\r\n\032,"Hierarchical Data Format (version 5) data"]
4294967190 == 0 = 0
mget @0: \037\213\b\000\370\325\344L\000\003\354<\373s\332\306\326\375\325\376+62\267@B0\344&\355\255\035
```

Finally it falls with a message:

```
 [ 0 string,=8BPS,"image/x-photoshop"]

4 == 0 = 0
Adding tstore/partner/admin/pay_affiliates.php
svn: E000024: Can't open file '/var/svn/repos/db/transactions/0-3.txn/next-ids': Too many open files
```

I've googled but have not found anything.
I'm using the latest version:

```
 #svn --version

svn, version 1.7.2 (r1207936)
```

RHEL5.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you created your repository ?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problems is the error message you got:

```
svn: E000024: Can't open file '/var/svn/repos/db/transactions/0-3.txn/next-ids
```

which means that your repository area has not correctly set permissions...I assume that the folder /var/svn/repos/ has not correctly set permission for the set-uid flag.

Comment: Permissions are correct. It is obviously that smth. is not OK with the svn itself. Instead of adding files to a repo, it dislays a bunch of corrupted lines.

Comment: Can you give a list of the structure including the permission (ls -al) ?